# Paas for Websocket

Tags: heroku, websocket, paas

I am looking for a WebSocket-enabled PAAS service. So far I have only experimented on Heroku and it works quite fine. Would you recommend other services?

Side question: I'm slightly worried about the billing. In the case of Heroku, it seems that usage is calculated via the time dynos are busy. I guess that in case of a Websocket connection, there may be a lot of idle time in between data exchange, and it would be fully billed anyway. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will bill you for the time the dyno is up, whether or not it is being used at all.

We've used `Pusher` as a complete websocket service, which allows you to asynchronously publish events from your main Heroku app and off-load the websocket connections and event publishing to Pusher.

They charge based on the volume of websocket traffic, which might be cheaper if you have a small volume or peaky traffic, and don't want to pay for a consistent set of dynos needed to service your peak traffic.